# How to validate a text with a custom regex validation with return type as true or false in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, angular7

I am new to Angular development. I have the following requirements.
In case of text field, we need to validate the data entered in the text field with a regular expression with some extra validation. In the .html file, the existing code is like this.

```
<input type="text" id="domainName" [pattern]="validateDomain()" [placeholder]="ComputeIPAddressMessages.DOMAIN_NAME_PLACEHOLDER" name="domainName" class="form-control"
              [(ngModel)]="computeIPAddress.domainName" [disabled]="disabledComponent" #domainNameModel="ngModel"
               size="20" required>
<span class="tooltip-content">
            {{ComputeIPAddressMessages.INVALID_DOMAIN_NAME}}
            </span>
```

In the corresponding .ts file, the code is like this.

```
public validateDomain(): any {
    return CommonConstants.DOMAIN_NAME_REGEX;
  }
```

There are few new requirements so that I have to strip the contents of the html text and I have to do some manipulations before performing regular expression match.

SO I want to write method like this.

```
public validateDomain(): any {
        // Check if the domain name already exists or not
        // If the domain name start with .(period) or -(hyphen), remove it
        // Other check

        // perform some regular expression validation
       // Return either true or false
        return true or false;
      }
```

Is it possible in case of Angular 7 ? Please suggest and help me to achieve it. This is the way I want to do custom regex validation instead of directly passing a regular expression.

Comment: send a string to this `validateDomain(domain){if() return true; else false}`

Comment: Hi Prashant, can I write like this `[pattern]="validateDomain(domain){if() return true; else false}"`

Comment: Could please help me with an example ?

Comment: with [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) i think is not possible to return true or false

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz demo? Will try

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, I want with pattern if possible, I may not be able to share the code. I am java guy, I was thinking to solve in the java way. If you have any other suggestion, please help me.

Comment: I am not sure about pattern *(as I didn't try)* but my logic will be -- *On textbox `blur` event call on method from TS file which will be responsible to validate domain name if invalid then error will display and will disable submit button* or *will use Reactive forms to set the validation with valid domain*

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to give extra validations aside from regex patterns in [pattern] or pattern attribute in Angular as per my knowledge. The best way to handle it is using traditional **(change)** event in the html input tag and corresponding function call from component file. Add a boolean flag **isInvalidDomain** which will set to **true** when the pattern along with your conditions after doing your manipulations are not matching and set to **false** if validations are matching.

**sample.html**

```
<input type="text" id="domainName" (change)="validateDomain()" [placeholder]="ComputeIPAddressMessages.DOMAIN_NAME_PLACEHOLDER" name="domainName" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="computeIPAddress.domainName" [disabled]="disabledComponent" #domainNameModel="ngModel" size="20" required>
<span class="tooltip-content" *ngIf="isInvalidDomain"> {{ComputeIPAddressMessages.INVALID_DOMAIN_NAME}}
</span>
```

**yourcomponent.ts**

```
isInvalidDomain :boolean = false;
    validateDomain(){
       if(condition1 == true){
          if(computeIPAddress.domainName.test(CommonConstants.DOMAIN_NAME_REGEX)){
              this.isInvalidDomain = false;
            // success condition code
          } else {
              this.isInvalidDomain = true;
           }
       } else {
              this.isInvalidDomain = true;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I will definitely check it out and let you know about it.

Comment: No, I tried in various ways also as suggested by you, it is not working.